# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code for flutter project in xcode 13.4.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, flutter-dependencies

when i'm trying to build the archive then i get this error. please help me out from this issues.
thanks
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Along with removing derived data (xcode -> preferences -> locations -> Derived data), remove podfile.lock file also and do the following

```
flutter clean 
flutter pub get
cd ios 
pod install
```

Answer (score 1):

Please clear Derived data first
from `xcode -> preferences -> locations -> Derived data` -> move to bin and remove from bin as well.
Now do

```
flutter clean 
flutter pub get
cd ios 
pod install
pod update
```

and try to run app again

Comment: yeah, i will do but it's not working for me.

Comment: /bin/sh -c /Users/sarwarahmed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gaqkuxgcveeuuxgjtvlnelsvejcf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh


Failed to package /Users/sarwarahmed/Desktop/User_App.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Answer (score 0):

**for me i solved this issues just downgreade flutter sdk version 3.0.2 to 3.0.1 and it's work perfectly.**

thanks guys.
happy coding